# How to set different cookies for different instances of Chromium embedded browser

Tags: delphi, cookies, setcookie, chromium-embedded

I'm working on an application that requires multiple embedded instances and each of this instance logins to the same external site with different authentication details.

I'm using CEF (Chromium embedded framework ) in Delphi , I have a folder that i stored the cookies on it for different instance of my browsers , So i have this code in the first unit

```
     procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  form33 := Tform3.Create(nil);

  form33.Show;
end;
```

when the form33  created

```
    procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  CookieManager: ICefCookieManager;
  folder: string;

begin

  Randomize;

  Chromium1.SetBrowserID(Random(1244));

  folder := Randomtext(5);
  if DirectoryExists(folder) = False then
    MkDir(folder);

  CookieManager := TCefCookieManagerRef.Global;
  path := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + folder;

  CookieManager.SetStoragePath(path, true);

end;
```

The problem is that when i open two or more of instances of the form33 , i can't have for each browser in each form33 a specific cookie ...

Comment: You haven't said which version of DCEF you use, so let's assume that you used DCEF3. You should create a new manager for each instance by [`TCefCookieManagerRef.New(Path)`](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/src/ceflib.pas#14258) and store the returned reference into some private field of your form. In short, stop using `TCefCookieManagerRef.Global`.

Comment: Okay , i'm using DCEF3 , and i just tried your suggestion but it does not work for me ... any other suggestions ?
the problem is that the when i open a session in a Form33 instance and then open another Form33 instance , i find the same session open in the chromium of this new instance ... :(

Comment: I'm afraid I won't have other suggestions. It should be enough making a reference of `ICefCookieManager` interface for each instance of your CEF browser, store this reference to a private field, and return it to the `Result` parameter of the `OnGetCookieManager` event method (which I forgot to mention in my previous comment).

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to post an answer if you (or someone else) want to ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new manager for each instance by `TCefCookieManagerRef.New(Path)` and store the returned reference into some private field of your form. Then you need to return the stored reference to the `Result` parameter of the `OnGetCookieManager` event method:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chromium1: TChromium;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Chromium1GetCookieManager(Sender: TObject;
      out Result: ICefCookieManager);
  private
    FCookieManager: ICefCookieManager2;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCookieManager := TCefCookieManagerRef.New('C:\UniquePathToTheCookieStorage');
end;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1GetCookieManager(Sender: TObject;
  out Result: ICefCookieManager);
begin
  Result := FCookieManager;
end;
```