# What is the correct way to isolate cookies/users in Chromium embedded browser?

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium, embedded-browser

I have searched for days with no solution in sight.

I need multiple Chromium instances in one single application and each of this instance logins to the same site with different account (ex: outlook.com).

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24984198/4921614) but there's no "OnGetCookieManager" event in DECF3 new version. Apparently there was a [related bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1043) and event onGetCookieManager [was removed in the 1547 CEF3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/delphichromiumembedded/b2A8dsi1iB4/DinkRNaFNlgJ).

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869366/different-cookie-handlers-for-two-chromium-instances-on-one-form) but it doesn't work too.

Is this really possible? How?

I'm using DCEF3 (revision: 0cc175e7a629) and Delphi XE3.

Comment: I'm looking at it from a C++ API perspective. If I find something I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what CEF3 maintainer told me:
"Cookies can be stored globally, per request context or something else entirely. It depends on whether you pass a CefRequestContext to CreateBrowser*() and what you return from CefRequestContextHandler::GetCookieManager."

I'm not entirely sure how CreateBrowser is exposed in Delphi (I only use the C++ API), but I can confirm that GetCookieManager still exists in trunk (as the only method of CefRequestContextHandler).

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre apparently the delphi wrapper does not expose this way. I'm trying to understand the DCEF implementation.

Comment: Vi que é de Florianópolis, sou de itajaí.